# Homeomorphic image of $D^m$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Define
$$D^m=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{m+1} : ||x|| \leq 1 \}$$

Suppose $A$ and $D^m$ are homeomorphic , then is it necessary that $A$ is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

I thought that homeomorphism sends open sets to open sets, but it is not the case. Hence I cannot use that. I wonder if this statement is true. Can I get some hint?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since $D^m$ is compact $A$ is also compact. But $\Bbb R^n$ is Hausdorff, so compact subsets are closed.
The compactness argument is really necessary here, take for example $[0,+\infty)$ and $[0,1)$. These subsets (with the subspace topology) are homeomorphic but the first is closed in $\Bbb R$ while the second is not.

Comment: Yes, Considering the Sierpinski space on $X=\{0,1\}$ with the topologies $\tau=\{ \phi, \{0\}, X\}$, then considering the map $f:\{0\} \to \{1\}$ will give us the counterexample to the fact that homeomorphims sends closed sets to closed sets

Answer (score 2):

$D^m$ is compact, and so is every set homeomorphic to $D^m$. In $\mathbb R^n$ every compact is closed.